# what this class name means in java "1.org.hibernate.tutorial.domain6.TUser@198cb3d "?

Tags: java, hibernate

I notice that this class has a @ sign.

I know that a $ sign means a innner class.

so, what the @ means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an arbitrary separator character between the class name and the hexidecimal hexadecimal representation of the object's hash code. `toString` is being invoked on the `TUser` object. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a class name. It's the result of calling toString() when the class hadn't overridden it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an Anotation. For example, right click a package of your choice -> new -> ANotation. You should see an at symbol in the new Anotation.